# What are the Key Gameplay Differences between Valve's DOTA 2 vs League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends, dota-2

Valve's new game [DotA 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dota_2) is a sequel to the popular Warcraft 3 map of the same name which is nearing release. The game follows the same paradigm of a similar game, [League of Legends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Legends) which was inspired from the original DotA map.

Both games follow the same idea of leveling of a character, gaining items and hunting down non-player controlled monsters and player-controlled heroes with the ultimate goal of destroying the opponent's base.

Outside of these core genre-specific concepts, what would a veteran League of Legends player find to be new gameplay concepts when transitioning into DotA 2 (excluding differences in Heros, Terrain and Items)?

Comment: He is asking about DotA 2, not DotA.  This should be reopened unless there is another question it is duping that is specific to DotA 2

Comment: @RentheUnclean DotA2 is a port of DotA. The differences between either game and LoL are identical.

Comment: @RentheUnclean This is being [debated](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4309/is-dota-the-same-game-as-dota2)

Comment: Then the other question should be changed to something like: "What are the differences between the Defense of the Ancients series (DotA and DotA2) and League of Legends (LoL)?"  As is, this question is not actually answered on the site.

Comment: Alrighty, that was basically an essay, but it was fun. =)

Comment: Is there anything specific you're looking for, Resorath? I read your updates but can't really think of anything to add that fits into the concept of general information. Alternatively, if there's anything you disagree with from your experiences as a LoL player I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: @Decency I just updated it due to recent meta discussions. No changes needed.

Comment: DOTA2 is the original genre. It has better gameplay, competitive, soft graphics. Its tough learning curve makes ppl go towards LOL, and I have played LOL its graphics are very harsh and they copied Dota

Answer (score 179, accepted):

This question has been a long time coming. My answer will undoubtedly be Dota 2 biased because after playing both I feel that it is by far the better competitive game. However, I also believe that everything I say will be accurate- if anything isn't, or you feel there's something I've missed or should clarify, please point it out and I'm happy to change it. Hopefully I've made this worth reading.

### Within the games

#### Metagame

Dota 2 has an incredibly versatile metagame. Junglers are optional, with dual or unorthodox junglers presenting themselves at times. Trilanes, where three allied heroes on the same team group remain in close proximity from the beginning of the game, as well as roamers, where one or more heroes has no set place on the map and moves about as needed, are both common.  Lanes and roles are incredibly fluid to the point where attempting to define many heroes, or even predicting how a single 5-hero composition will lane, becomes difficult.

League of Legends has a relatively stable metagame. Convention dictates that an AD carry and a support go bottom, an AP carry goes mid, and a sustainer goes top, with the 5th man- an all but required jungler, left to his devices. These roles have not changed in at least a year of high level gameplay and across multiple tournaments.

League of Legends also introduced the concept of Summoner spells, which on the surface is an excellent addition to the depth of the genre. However, the power of "Flash," a short-distance blink spell, makes it all but required by every player, essentially just adding a high cooldown blink to every hero. The majority of Summoner spells are simply copies of items or abilities in Dota 2. League of Legends also includes Runes and Masteries, advantages which players can take with them into the beginning of the game. In competitive play, these for the most part seem relatively static.

#### The Laning Phase

As I've already mentioned, the lanes in LoL are very similar from game to game. This makes movement between them easily noticeable; only the jungler can truly gank unpredictably. When coupled with the Flash ability, which grants every character a teleport from the start of the game, and towers which deal huge amounts of damage, action at low levels becomes incredibly rare. It is not uncommon for the first kill of a LoL match to happen 5-10 minutes into the game. In Dota 2, this is nearly unheard of: first blood happening before the creeps even spawn is more common than a game going so long without a death.

A majority of spells in LoL are inherently spammable. They cost a low percentage of a character's mana pool, or none at all, and can be used extremely frequently to pressure a lane and test an opponent's ability to "sustain" themselves. Many of these abilities are skillshots which need to be landed as much as possible. The spells are for harass and are predictable, and dying to spells like this as a high level player simply doesn't happen: it's very clear what's coming.

Conversely, a key concept of laning in Dota 2 is simply "... go." What I mean by this is that when two allies in a lane decide to make an attempt to kill an enemy, you will know it. Rarely seen spells with high mana costs and large impact come out and decide the fight based on the players' judgment of the situation and execution of their attempt. The availability of such abilities dictates how safely you can lane against opponents. In effect, it comes down to a simple challenge: I think I can stay alive if I stand here. If you don't think I can- prove it. A simple AoE stun on a hero such as Sven or Sand King can cost as much as 75% of the hero's base mana pool, and without the mana to use such a spell these heroes are just big creeps. Other spells can be somewhat spammed, but very few Heroes cast spells in lane half as much as Champions in LoL do: you simply don't have the mana for it. In the early laning phase, this mana is as valuable as health, the latter of which can be quickly restored with consumables. Mana potions are more difficult to use, as they last 30 seconds and are dispelled upon taking damage.

These consumables are noteworthy only because of another aspect unique to Dota 2, the courier. Utilization of the courier to bring items to you makes being beaten down in your lane somewhat acceptable- as long as you don't actually die. After healing up, you're still at full mana and because your opponents probably took damage and used mana in the kill attempt, the balance of power in the lane may have swung the other way.

#### Denying

For some reason, denying has become a crux of the argument between League of Legends and Dota 2. To be perfectly honest, it doesn't really matter anywhere near as much as people pretend. The simplest way to explain the role of denying, to me, is to imagine a game of musical chairs. Dota 2 gives two people one chair and has them fight over it every time there's a minion/creep to kill. League of Legends takes the same two people and gives them each their own chair: no one loses.

When you expand this concept to towers is when denying gains huge importance. In Dota 2, if an enemy tower is below 10% HP it is capable of being denied and thus your team is on the verge of losing a lot of potential gold. If your team does not press the issue to force a conflict at the tower, you will lose out on that bonus. In League of Legends, you can just walk away if the other team wants to defend their tower. It's not going anywhere and you have nothing to lose by leaving. If the fight doesn't seem to be in your favor, there's no reason for it to happen.

It's also worth noting that denying minions/creeps allows a team to control lane equilibrium. If they've taken an enemy tower, a team with superior lane control can still keep creep clashes on their side of the map and force the enemy to make the moves. The actual power of a deny to limit experience and gold to an enemy isn't half as important as the overarching strategies it allows.

#### Ganking and Teamfights

In high level League of Legends ganks are infrequent, and with good reason: a gank doesn't really set your opponent back very much. Because Champions don't lose gold when dying, even if a gank is successful its opportunity cost to the killer may be worth more potential gold and experience than what is negated to his opponent.

Because of this, action in League of Legends revolves around what conflicts of interest on the map there are: specifically Baron Nashor and the Dragon. These conflicts force only a few large scale teamfights that happen at predictable times and usually decide the match.

In Dota 2, while fights at Roshan are frequent, they are only one of many reasons for fights to happen, with a simple gank capable of evolving in mere seconds to a large scale teamfight. We'll see the reason for this next.

#### Items

The single item that Dota 2 benefits from the most is the Town Portal or TP Scroll. While it exists in League of Legends in the form of the Teleport Summoner Spell, it's on a massive 5 minute cooldown and requires you to give up a valuable spell slot. In Dota 2, for a small gold cost and an item slot, your hero is capable of being in a defensible position on your part of the map or at a tower in three seconds. You can assist an ally being ganked, stop a tower push, or even move across the map to catch an opponent by surprise. You're also capable of escaping to safety at your well in the same short span of time, but only if you can outsmart your opponents.

The mobility offered by the TP Scroll is absolutely crucial to the fluidity of the game; I cannot even imagine how different Dota 2 would be without the item. The potential it offers is enormous, and it's why hero movement in the game is so difficult to keep track of. A hero can kill someone in bottom lane, immediately teleport to an allied tower top that's under attack, and win a teamfight there for his team. Heroes are constantly shifting around between lanes to gain advantages where they see fit: the ability to be aware of all five of them, often through pure intuition, is one of the biggest differences between a casual Dota 2 player and a competitive one.

Items in Dota 2 are very attention-demanding. It is not at all uncommon for a single hero to have four or five items that are activatable and time-sensitive at any given point in the game. Non-activatable items in Dota 2 are very simplistic: if you want a critical strike, you must build Crystalis. If you want to boost your gold intake, you build Hand of Midas, an item that gives bonus gold with every use, on a cooldown. For silencing an opponent, spawning illusions, teleporting, granting your hero various immunities, etc., each item performs a very specific role and the choice of items is a monumental one for heroes and teams, never mind the actual usage of such items.

Items in League of Legends are relatively interwoven. There are multiple different items with similar themes that have various flavors. There are four items, for instance, that all grant passive cooldown reduction and passive gold over time. Items in LoL are overwhelmingly passive- while there are some useful activatable items, the benefits they give are minor compared to the very powerful and situational abilities of items in Dota 2, such as a BKB which can grant complete magical immunity for up to 10 seconds, or a Blink Dagger which conditionally allows a hero to teleport nearly a screen's width on a 14 second cooldown. Most of the activatable items in League of Legends deal with dealing/preventing damage or affecting movement speed. None grant any form of true disable.

Many consumables such as health potions and wards that grant vision in an area are shared between the games. League of Legends simplifies their usage: these consumables may not be shared and are not subject to enemy intervention. Use of potions in Dota 2 requires care, since they can be interrupted by enemy damage, but also allows for hyped moments where a player makes a great play by juking enemy attacks while using a health potion to gain a quick burst of health and turn an otherwise decided fight.

#### Fog of War

Fog of War in Dota 2 is simple, but manipulative. If there is not a direct line of sight between an allied unit and an enemy, you are not seen. This allows players to hide behind treelines (trees are destructible by many heroes and various items) and make their presence known only at opportune times.

Fog in LoL is primarily due to "brush," a mechanic where units in brush locations can remain unseen despite being very near to enemies. These locations are static and are frequently warded or scouted with abilities, making their actual impact minimal and more a matter of "did you check that spot?" than anything else.

#### Runes versus Blue/Red Buffs

In Dota 2, there is a single powerup called a Rune which spawns every two minutes. This grants a hero double damage, huge health/mana regeneration, invisibility, maximum movement speed, or spawns two hallucinations of the hero that have various uses. Only one of the teams can get this powerup and a sizable percentage of early game kills are a direct result of one of these Runes.

In LoL, the Red/Blue buffs are spawned by neutral creeps in each team's jungle. As in the case of denies: both teams have the same thing, so there is no impetus to fight over it if the fight doesn't seem to be to your advantage. The buffs in LoL are no less impactful than those in Dota 2, but the advantages they give don't help much when ganking. You can safely assume that an enemy jungler in LoL has a red buff- if you try to assume that a roaming ganker in Dota 2 has an invisibility rune you will never be able to accomplish anything, and so you're forced to make calculated risks.

#### Gamechanging moments

This is the section most deserving of expansion, but to anyone without a decent grasp of both games it's virtually impossible to explain. I've done my best.

Gamebreaking moments in Dota 2 are frequent and essentially define the game. A commonly chosen hero, Enigma, has an ability called Black Hole which can render an entire opposing team useless for 4 seconds, an absurdly long time in games of this genre. See [this teamfight](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzzQN4KGhA4). However, the difficulty in executing something like this is enormous and the penalty for misusing the spell, which can be interrupted easily and has a three minute cooldown, is enormous. In the same video that I linked to, the Enigma performs with textbook execution, even being creative by using another of his abilities to clear trees for positioning. However, his team still loses the fight: the opponents have reacted properly to his team's composition by buying items with significant effects (Mekansm and Pipe). When his teammates don't follow up on his initiation properly, it costs them the battle. Games of Dota 2 can and have been won from the use of a single ability.

Conversely, in League of Legends, spells have become more standard and less dramatic. Their cooldowns have been reduced, their effects lessened, and their impact often unnoticeable. Teamfights in LoL are not so much about tactical selection of targets or timing as they are about casting all of your spells and hitting something with them. This is why the concept of a "tank" is able to exist in League of Legends but is completely foreign to Dota 2: good players don't use spells on heroes simply because they're in front, but in LoL it's often the correct course of action.

#### Action

Something a lot of people like to compare is the amount of action a single typical game will have. I took a look at 30 VOD's from the most recent LoL and Dota 2 tournaments and compiled information in a public spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Atwn_lcLizk9dDRBNjk2UDAySm9rZ2FBWXdmZ0hLaUE#gid=0). It's not a huge sample size, but it gives a pretty good picture of an average game, nonetheless. There are some outliers that probably slightly influence the results, specifically the longest Dota 2 game I'm aware of at an absurd 86 minutes long.

- **LoL:** Games last about 38 minutes. A typical game averages about 29 total kills between the two teams. There are 0.78 kills per minute, or about 8 kills every 10 minutes, on average.
- **Dota 2:** Games last about 44 minutes. A typical game averages about 56 kills between the two teams. There are 1.37 kills per minute, or about 14 kills every 10 minutes, on average.

### Outside the games

#### eSports Features

Dota 2 has an incredible replay and spectator system. Not only can players tune into essentially any game on a two minute delay, they can hear commentary by anyone in broadcasting slots choosing to utilize the feature. They can choose to operate their own camera, follow a commentator's, follow a single player's perspective, or even allow the very adept computer to automatically decide the most action-intensive location; never missing a kill. Any public or matchmaking game has replays which are freely downloadable by upcoming players. Valve has also announced that Dota 2 will have LAN support, putting it even a step above competing games like StarCraft 2. Teammates can both voice chat with each other and strategize by drawing on the minimap.

League of Legends has a replay system created by a third party developer that is very quirky and comparatively unusable. There is no voice chat in the game. League of Legends has the advantage of a team matchmaking system which allows up and coming teams to scrimmage against each other easily. I do not know if this is actually utilized as advertised or if Dota 2 plans to emulate the feature.

#### Player Base

While LoL constantly heralds the amount of "active players" it maintains, it neither specifies what constitutes "active" nor how many concurrent players the game has at any given time. Dota 2 is currently peaking at slightly over 30,000 concurrent players, but at least five times that number are playing the original DotA on GArena at any given time, in addition to uncountable players on other DotA clients, including the now antiquated Battle.net. As the availability of invites to the closed beta of Dota 2 increases, the number of players will surely grow. Attempting to say whether it will end up bigger that LoL is difficult if not impossible due to LoL's information hiding.

#### Competitive Community

Na'Vi is absolutely crushing Dota 2 right now- anyone who contests this is not watching much competitive gameplay. There are various other highly successful teams, the majority of them Eurasian, with only a few North American teams distinguishing themselves. The most well known of these North American teams is FIRE, now coL., who came essentially out of nowhere to secure themselves both a sponsorship and a respected international presence. Most of the sponsored Asian teams have to this point stuck with the original DotA. This is largely due to a televised DotA league in the country called the G-League. This is expected to change in the near future, however, as some of the bigger names still playing Chinese DotA have already announced their switch to Dota 2.

League of Legends on the other hand has a relatively international competitive scene, with multiple top teams from all areas of the world. Worth mentioning is the Korean television channel known for its StarCraft content, OGN, which recently announced that it will be hosting shows for League of Legends.

Both games have teams supported by huge sponsors, with multiple of the biggest names like CLG, Na'Vi, Dignitas, mTw, and plenty of others sponsoring both Dota 2 and LoL teams. Other well-known gaming organizations like Complexity, SK, and Fnatic are undecided, having sponsored and dropped teams from both games at times. Finally, teams like EG and TSM have apparently settled into one game or the other, though if one game comes to dominate the scene I wouldn't doubt that either would ignore it, with the popularity organizations like those two can both swing.

#### Important Figures

In this genre, there are several key people who stand apart from others in terms of developing the scene surrounding the games:

- Eul: As the first serious developer of DotA for WarCraft3, Eul's contributions include core mechanics of the genre that at this point we take for granted. He now works at Valve contributing to the development of Dota 2.
- Guinsoo: As the creator of DotA All-Stars, Guinsoo combined popular aspects from various versions of the game that had sprung up around the original, acting as a filter for innovation. Guinsoo now works with Riot Games in helping to develop League of Legends.
- Pendragon: Pendragon began hosting a DotA-related website in 2004. The website, http://dota-allstars.com/, acted as the foundation for the community around the game to grow and only came to an end when he announced that he was moving to work with League of Legends and archiving the site.
- Icefrog: The developer who pushed DotA to new heights with his focuses on balance and competitive play is frequently deified by his fans. IceFrog was the primary developer of DotA throughout its competitive explosion and the arrival of its legitimacy as an eSport. He formerly (and secretly) worked for S2 Games in the development of Heroes of Newerth and left under equally unclear terms, likely after finding the environment at S2 unsuited to the degree of creative control he wanted. Shortly after that departure, he announced his involvement with Valve as the head of a team bringing us what we now know as Dota 2.

#### Developer Support

League of Legends has a competitive scene that is largely subsidized by Riot Games. The developer sponsors tournaments, funds prize pools, and organizes competitive environments. Dota 2 awarded the biggest prize pool ever at the $1.6 million "International" run by Valve. However, it also has multiple high quality events like The Defense and The Premier League with well known industry sponsors like Twitch.tv and Razer that are completely unaffiliated with Valve. I am not aware of any such competitions for League of Legends.

The different ways that Dota 2 and LoL update their games is also something worth covering:

The developers of League of Legends nerf a lot of powerful things, see their most recent patch [here](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/V1.0.0.136) for details. What this does is push everything to the middle in terms of balance, where it's more simple to tweak anything that gets too weak or too strong.

[Alternatively](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Version_6.74), here is Dota 2's most recent patch. Exactly three things were seriously weakened, all of which were regarded by many as broken mechanics. (Dark Seer's Agh's Wall, Invoker Tornado/EMP, and Puck's Phase Shift autocast). Each of those heroes that was nerfed was also significantly improved in other ways, to maintain their power. Outside of that, something like 40 heroes that were considered underused were buffed- many of them quite significantly.

Dota 2 maintains power by making everyone powerful, LoL keeps everyone approximately in the middle and tweaks the ends. Attempting to say which approach provides an overall better game balance is largely a subjective argument, so I won't make it.

### In Closing

I feel that despite the absurd length of this message I've still failed to cover so much, but that's part of the reason these games are so popular: there is an enormous amount to learn and improve upon and attempting to write a guide for even a single aspect of either game would be a monumental task. In a single sentence, the major difference is that the games are not built for the same purpose.

Dota 2 is constructed with the mindset that competitive players have the utmost priority. If this means that the average player is neglected, it doesn't matter to the game: it is not being developed for players who are not at the highest level. If a new hero is added, it's because the competitive metagame would benefit from such a hero, not because Valve needs to earn money. If a hero is made weaker, it's not because he's strong in public games, it's because he's strong when the two best teams in the world square off.

League of Legends is built with a model that requires an influx of "new" to create revenue. Whether that's new customers, new characters, or new skins, it doesn't matter: the game is developed to bring in constant money. In order to continue that, Riot Games needs to ease entry into League of Legends for new players and then convince them to stick around. It doesn't matter if the competitive players think Flash is a stupid mechanic or if top commentators want an improved replay system- the game isn't being prioritized for them.

To be perfectly frank, Dota 2 is incredibly hard. When you start to play the game, you will play your first hundred games and still feel like you have no grasp whatsoever of what you're doing. You will get frustrated with the game and at times you'll probably have to step away. But if you love the thrill of the razor's edge scenario, you'll be back. League of Legends tones that down at both extremes. When you're learning the game, you won't become anywhere near as frustrated because mistakes aren't punished as heavily. For example: the more you die, the less each successive death rewards the enemy team- a design decision clearly made with public play in mind. When you make gameplay decisions with such priorities, the peak gameplay suffers as a result.

The cutthroat style of Dota 2 is simply not something that everyone will appreciate- ignoring that concept is asinine. The argument can definitely be made that Valve is overdoing it- their lack of accommodation for players looking to learn the game is noteworthy and I feel that it holds back an otherwise extraordinary game. In the end, however, Dota 2's focus on high level play makes the game incredible to watch once you begin to understand its nuances, and the depth and replayability of it as an eSport is unmatched both within the genre and across all others. In time, I fully expect others to come to appreciate that.

Comment: Can't the stability of the metagame, and the isues you say are solved, really be attributed more to the fact LoL has been out for not-quite-three years, versus Dota 2's not-quite-one? Eventually Dota 2 metagame possibilities will stabilize and paradigm changes will slow, and its individual systems will accumulate the same solved cruft. Likewise, as the individual systems are solved the "gamebreaking moments" start becoming expected, then planned, and then uninteresting. That's not a difference between the two games, it's just age.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig That would be a legitimate point except for that the fact that Dota2's metagame right now has already become completely different from DotA just by nature of the limited hero selections and subtle changes. It's done so in less than a year. In the nearly three years that LoL has been out DotA itself has gone through numerous metagame shifts, with another one expected soon as new heroes hit. If LoL has had even a single shift, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig As for the gamebreaking moments, people have been dropping Engima ultimates on entire teams for 5+ years. I don't see it getting uninteresting anytime soon. It doesn't matter if you know it's coming, it still comes in the half second of time your team is standing too close to each other. That's about the window Enigma had to hit in the video I posted. I also added a section on how the developers patch their games that your point made me think of!

Comment: Only point I would disagree on would be line of sight for league of legends. It's far more fluid than Dota2, preventing obvious ganks, but can also be used to trick players into rounding corners to a five-man gank.

Comment: @Domocus If I'm understanding you right, that aspect is shared by Dota2 in the form of cliffs and ramps, so I ignored it for both games.

Comment: @Decency, obviously you haven't been a long time League of Legends player.  The metagame has been changing as it used to be (in NA at least) ranged AD mid, double tank bot, double top and no jungler.  Eventually, it changed to a solo top and a jungler, where the solo top was someone who can 2v1 pretty good, like ChoGath.  Only around season 1 championship at Dreamhack did it start becoming a regular support/AD bot lane.  But even Dreamhack showed the EU metagame being double AP in the mid and top which fNatic ran.  At GamesCom, the NA metagame changed this to Bruiser top instead of AP.

Comment: I haven't played Dota2, but I hear that you aren't allowed to surrender in it, while you can in League of Legends.  This supports your opinion that Dota2 is not friendly to newer players, as I can imagine a one-sided game against a sadistic team going on for hours with the other team unable to do anything to stop it.  They could continually slaughter the other team until the other team completely gives up on playing the game ever again.  At least that's what I'd feel like.  I was interested about Dota2 until I heard there was that "feature" in it...

Comment: @Decency, lastly the more you die in LoL does give less gold to the enemy, however gold isn't so significant as the respawn timers where your team is now forced to 4v5 if they wish to contest anything.  The respawn timers increase each time you die, so dying is still bad.

Comment: @Decency, the more I read over your opinion editorial the more I question it.  Anyways, I have no idea of the player base numbers in terms of people playing it, but the people that follow the competitive scene is known.  I believe the recent numbers of IEM Hannover championship for League of Legends topped at around 250k that watched the stream.  At other events, these numbers have reached over 100k consistently.  That is people who are interested in watching competitive players play what you describe to be a "stagnant" metagame.

Comment: @user22193 You aren't allowed to forfeit in Dota2. I'm actually hoping that that is changed, but I don't really get a vote. The longest I've had a game that was essentially over get dragged out is no more than 10 minutes or so, so while it's not a huge deal it is annoying when it happens. Most teams are happy to quickly end the game when your team gives up.

Comment: @user22193 As for the respawn timer increasing, are you sure on that? I've never heard that before and can't find anything to corroborate what you said. True that dying can give a team a 4v5 for a Baron or Dragon, but also true that dying when those things have both been killed is thus not a very big deal. Sometimes it gives teams a tower push. I could potential cover the role of buybacks in Dota2, since they're often a pretty important factor to games.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2903/discussion-between-decency-and-user22193)

Comment: @Decency not sure how to chat.  For the respawn timer, simply get yourself killed and look at how long it takes for you to respawn, then die again, and look.  If you want, you can compare it from one game to the next.  Not sure what the formula is, but as I am an expert in getting killed in League of Legends, it is something I noticed while looking at my gray screen since there isn't too much else to do.

Comment: @User22193 It's variant based on the length of the game and your Champion's level, so dying later will make you last longer.

Comment: @Decency I Agree with great part of what you said, but you tend TOO MUCH to DOTA2 and does not show all the good points of LoL. You also makes a lot of blind comments (as you said that everyone has flash, what is not how it works, and you don't say that the FoW on LoL is better than in DOTA2 (instead you say DOTA is the better one) Ther is a FoW in LOL, not only brush, and players stay behind trees and walls (unbreakable too) to make they appearance when it's needed. It's an amazing answer, but you really feather one's own nest on DOTA2

Comment: In LoL, tactical selection of targets is quite common in team fights. Usually players point out when an opposing player is quite strong and needs to be taken down quickly, or when someone who's building resistance, to avoid them, etc. (Unless I misinterpreted your sentence). Also, targeting someone at the front of a team is something common among newer players, thinking they should just try to blow up anything that's bad in front of them. People who know what they're doing tend to avoid the person at the front of the team fight, unless it's the intended target that needs to be shut down.

Comment: While this is an absurdly long answer and I appreciate your effort you could simply say "LoL sucks DOTA2 rocks." or to point out the point: "If you want competitive play go DOTA2 otherwise go LoL"

Comment: @edem I don't think anyone who has played both would disagree that Dota2 is the more competitive or that LoL is the more casual-oriented game. I wanted to cover a lot of actual differences, which I did. Since this community is much more predominantly LoL players I'm not remotely surprised at the critical comments. But I'm pretty confident that I've played more LoL than those criticizing have played Dota2, so I'm content with my answer.

Comment: Maybe the right solution instead of criticizing Decency's lean towards DotA 2 is to  edit his answer to add more League thoughts into it? I am already trying to think of something I can add but he's done a decent job of covering ground (see what I did thar?)

Comment: This answer is so long that it would be hard to write an actual counter-answer which would be leaning to more objective. Ideally, I would edit the answer to add some things from LoL. Because while this is a very extensive answer, it's completely in the form of "LoL does that. Dota 2 does that better". And because of this leaning, unfortunately, the answer is not really objective, or giving a neutral comparison.

Comment: Things which could be added: LoL has a built in "teleport to base", as opposed to the TP and couriers. Towers are different. In LoL, they are a real threat, cementing the early game. About items, the tendency in LoL tends to change in Season 3, with the addition of a lot of active abilities on them. They still remain much more passive, compared to Dota2. Besides, the "musical chairs" metaphor is rather wrong. You can't kill your minions in LoL, so the way to to actually deny is to zone out the opponent. The accent is more about poking the opponent than denying, then.

Comment: Since the sustain is stronger, and spells are less dramatic, the lane phase in LoL is more about zoning and positioning for the good opportunity. In Dota 2, where the CC and bursts are much stronger, it's of an issue of taking the occasion. Poking doesn't matter as much.

Comment: @Gnoupi I just responded here: http://pastebin.com/wUnQFmbk ... figured that's easier than writing a bunch of comments. Do you play Dota2?

Comment: @Dec - I tried, didn't really manage to pass the initial wall of things to get the hang of it yet (nor do I have the time, recently, actually). My point was mostly about lack of some details, I don't particularly pretend one is better than the other, it shouldn't be the point of the answer here. My last comment is messy indeed, about zoning. I meant that it's more about long term positioning. It's much easier in Dota 2 to jump for a kill in a split second, early game, or equally get killed in a few seconds, caught by surprise, even at distances which seemed safe by LoL's standards

Comment: @Gnoupi If you don't know what heroes can do it's obviously going to be hard to judge where safe positioning is. When I update the answer I'll factor some of the stuff you mentioned in. Thanks.

Comment: I've started playing a lot of Dota 2 and being a veteran league player I think I have a lot to add to this. Should I edit your answer or provide another answer from the perspective of a league player?

Comment: @SadlyNot This is pretty out of date, though the major concepts are still valid- I'd suggest writing your own answer and if/when I ever update this I can factor in some of your points. There's plenty to add.

Comment: @Decency Yeah we can get a point/counter-point thing going if you want. That will be more useful than focusing on keeping your answer up-to-date.

Comment: @Decency: Incredible answer! However, perhaps the new game mode "Limited Heroes" and the training tutorial deserve mention as they facilitate the entry to DotA2 somewhat.

Comment: @Murch Thanks. The whole thing is at least a year out of date, so there's tons to update if I decide to do so. I haven't kept up with LoL much at all though, so I don't really think it'd be fair for me to make any further gameplay assertions.

Comment: There is a neat write-up from August 2013 about the similarities and differences between LoL and Dota2 on TeamLiquid from the perspective of LoL-Players: [Dota2 for LoL Players by Staboteur](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=423453#)

Comment: I strongly disagree about the a lot of what has been said here, I use to be a hardcore dota 2 player I would play a 100 games a WEEK at times and never get bored because the game was so exciting that being said I have not played dota 2 ever since I really started playing league of legends (LAST YEAR) I mean dota 2 was fun and all however league of legends in my opinion is very interesting in its own right and I have been hooked on the game since, the "DotA" maps on Garena and battle.net you mention I have played them and they are very different from DotA 2. Both games are good for whomever.

Comment: Well, since this was bumped to the frontpage: LoL is a bit misenterpeted here. While it's true that there's no actual necessity to fight, not fighting often leads to loss of map control which is the key element in LoL. Losing map control leads to a snowball effect (Jungle camps are impossible to take, minion experience is shared between 3-5 people at a time, risky to leave base). All of that combines into a reason why hail mary plays have to be made. Especially with changes that came after this post (Baron Buff = almost free tower destruction)

Comment: Not only that but denying is also very important in LOL, and while you can't kill your own minions to deny, you can poke which has the same effect (the enemy won't be able to farm if they're low - this is aided by lower mana costs). Furthermore fog of war doesn't work as said in this post, since while it's true that hiding in brush makes you "invisible", you can also use walls and stand behind brush to be hidden from sight

Comment: Regarding buffs, depending on the champion that champion will be extremely strong at ganking. Kindred, Graves and most auto attack junglers are pretty darn strong ganking with red buff (more auto dmg, HP regen and slows). Most times they get first blood by walking up to a lane and just auto attacking if the laner is pushed. On the other hand, champs like Hecarim, Amumu, Sejuani are beasts with blue buff because of the mana regen that allows them to me permanently casting spells.

Comment: And that's not even counting Elise or Lee Sin that can gank without either buff, but with the buff they're absolute beasts able to towerdive at level 3 (if they can avoid taking 2 tower shots)